# Cannot delete messages with specified timestamp

Tags: node.js, discord.js, momentjs

Hi Im having trouble deleting messages that were posted in a channel at a specific time. I'm checking and comparing the message timestamps with the moment.js module however when I run my code it's not deleting the messages at the duration I want it to rather than it will delete any message fetched.

So I'm stuck at this point.

Here is my code:

```
await channel.messages.fetch({limit: 100 })
        .then(messages => {
            messages.forEach(m => {
                let time = moment.utc(m.createdTimestamp).subtract( 7, 'days'); 
                if (time) {
                    channel.bulkDelete(10)
                }
```

The goal is that I want to delete messages that are 7 days or older.
Help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, you are subtracting 7 days from the time message was created. You probably want to subtract 7 days from NOW and compare it to `m.createdTimestamp`. Which leads to another problem:

You are not comparing two times, just checking if `time` object exists, which will always be true - you just created it a line above the `if` statement!  So all messages get deleted.

To sum it up:

1. Subtract 7 days from current moment and store it in variable `sevenDaysAgo`
2. in `if` statement, compare message creation time with `sevenDaysAgo`. If message is older than seven days ago, delete it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare the time of the message to the time seven days ago. The time in milliseconds 7 days ago can be calculated by `moment().subtract(7, 'days')`. We will compare the milliseconds, if the message is older than 7 days, the value in milliseconds will be less than the value from 7 days ago.

```
let time = moment.utc(m.createdTimestamp).subtract( 7, 'days');
if (time.milliseconds() < moment().subtract(7, 'days').milliseconds()) {
  channel.bulkDelete(10)
}
```